# libdvdcss error when using libdvdnav

Tags: c

I have a sample code which opens a DVD mounted on the /mnt/iso folder and prints the output on the screen.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dvdnav/dvdnav.h>
#include <dvdnav/dvdnav_events.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dvdnav_t *dvdnav;
    int finished, len, event;
    uint8_t buf[2050];
    /* Open the DVD */
    dvdnav_open(&dvdnav, "/mnt/iso");
    fprintf(stderr, "Reading...\n");
    finished = 0;
    while (!finished) {
        int result = dvdnav_get_next_block(dvdnav, buf, &event, &len);
        if (result == DVDNAV_STATUS_ERR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error getting next block (%s)\n",
                dvdnav_err_to_string(dvdnav));
            exit(1);
        }
        switch (event) {
            case DVDNAV_BLOCK_OK:
                /* Write output to stdout */
                fwrite(buf, len, 1, stdout);
                break;
            case DVDNAV_STILL_FRAME:
                fprintf(stderr, "Skipping still frame\n");
                dvdnav_still_skip(dvdnav);
                break;
            case DVDNAV_STOP:
                finished = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unhandled event (%i)\n", event);
                finished = 1;
        }
    }
    dvdnav_close(dvdnav);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile the code and run it I get the following error:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.1
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/loop1 mounted on /mnt/iso for CSS authentication
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/loop1 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/loop1 for reading
libdvdread: Device /dev/loop1 inaccessible, CSS authentication not available.
libdvdnav: Can't read name block. Probably not a DVD-ROM device.
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/user/.dvdnav/.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00c00000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Reading...
Unhandled event (9)
```

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is and it'd be great if someone could point the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well using the ISO file directly instead of mounting it worked for me. The CSS issue gets solved and it works properly.